# how to set custom color of table row

Tags: iphone, uitableview, colors

how to set custom color of table row  when it is clicked...

i mean i don't want that blue color which appear by Default....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get whatever color you want, you have to replace the selectedBackgroundView with your own UIView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIView *selectedBackground = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
        selectedBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackground;
    }
    // configure cell
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: yes, this will not work in grouped style. It's much harder to achieve the same thing with a grouped style. One way is to subclass UIView, like done in http://pessoal.org/blog/2009/02/25/customizing-the-background-border-colors-of-a-uitableview/

Answer (score 1):

you can set the tableView cell property

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your own subclass of UITableViewCell. Overwrite the method `-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected`

Something like this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
       [super setSelected:selected];
       if (selected) {
             self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
       } else {
             self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       }
}
```

Comment: +1 : ok but the problem is how to use it with my class which has already the tableview and which is subclass of UIViewController...actually a never used subclass of UITableViewCell...so please give idea accordingly....